# No-Parameter Constructor v/s Constructor with params

Tags: java

which one of below is better or to be prefered

```
new Object();  
Object.setValue1("1");  
Object.setValue2("2");  
Object.setValue3("3");
```

or

```
new Object("1","2","3");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I assume you're talking about the design of your own classes, rather than how to use other already-designed classes.)

Neither is always "better," it depends on the nature of the object and (to an extent) on your preferred style.

If an object cannot have a meaningful state without some external information, then requiring that information in the constructor makes sense, because then you can't create instances with an invalid state.

However, having constructors that require as little information as possible is useful in terms of making the class easy to use in a variety of situations. If the class is such that a zero-arguments constructor is feasible and doesn't complicate the class, it's great in terms of supporting various use-cases, including cases where the instance is being built as part of parsing some other structure (JSON, XML, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

There is also a third option that builds on the use of [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject().setValue1("1").setValue("2").setValue("3");
```

I personally like this approach but if the number of parameters is short and known at the time of construction AND the varying possible combinations of parameters is short then I would take the route of parameters on the constructor. I think most would agree that 12 constructor overloads are an eye sore.

Comment: Readability is important. All things being equal, I prefer a more readable method like the one described above, rather than a constructor with unknown parameters.

Comment: @GustavBertram I should clarify. State based data that an object needs is probably best served as constructor parameters. Adding in extras to an object is a good time to use this approach IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you know the values at the time of object construction.

If Yes, then use the constructor version if not then you will have to use the other version.

Ofcourse,Initialization through the Constructor version is faster because it involves just one function call over 3 set function calls and also it is more logical way.

Comment: so if i have all the values its better to go with the constructor with params version...

Comment: @Vincent I would say the answer to that depends on the number of parameters AND the varying possible combinations of parameters.

Comment: @Vincent:Yes,If all values are known at time of construction of your object,Use the param version.It is the best approach.

Comment: @Als: It's not always better to call parameterized constructor. When parameters to pass are way too big like set of Map containing list with some other parameters. You should always think about the size the parameters will take while defining parametrized constructor.

Comment: @HarryJoy:Not really,If your object cannot do anything meaningful without setting the values then there is no point in having an such an completely constructed object and than later spend additional set function calls to make the object useful.*It depends* being true,more often or less paramterized contructor will be the way to go.

Comment: @Als This is true for state that must absolutely be present at construction time I suppose but often there are many other side goodies a class offers that are crammed into the constructors as well and it just becomes a mess! So I'd say it is unsafe to make a blanket statement that in ALL cases it is better.

Comment: @MatthewCox: Yes that's what I'm trying to say. ***It's not always better to use parameterized constructor*** even if you know the values.

Answer (score 1):

Its always better performance to call in constructor If you know values already.

Comment: ***No.*** It's not always better to use parameterized constructor even if you know the values.

Comment: @HarryJoy: i think it will not be good if parameterized constructors are initializing other objects apart from string n stuff.is it??

Comment: @Vincent Which kind of other stuff? I'm not saying it is bad. You can/should use it but upto some limited number of parameters of specific parameter type. In short it should never result in out Of Memory or high memory operation.

Comment: @Vincent You can use anything as an argument in constructor just make sure it never result in a high memory operation.

Answer (score 1):

Then there is my preferred alternative.  Thing is the name of some interface.  It creates an anonymous class.

```
Thing createThing ( final int val1 , final int val2 , final int val3 )
{
         return new Thing ( )
         {
                // can use val1, val2, val3
         } ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the application.

Calling Parameterized constructor will be a good idea if at Compile time you know what values to be given to your variables, rather than calling Setters. Because you are calling 3 setter methods and in parameterized constructor, you are just passing to the cnostructor it self.

But if at compile time you don't know what values to be given then how can you call paramterized constructor.

But for initialization it will be better to call parameterized constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a semantic difference.  If (1) you are instantiating an object with an initial state.  In (2) you are changing the state of an existing instance (3 times).  It's a small difference but may become very important in more complex systems (especially if you rely on various JavaBean conventions).  But still, neither one is wrong or better.